# Batch - Commenting on YouTube

Tags: batch-file

I would like to create a simple program that can comment on youtube videos automatically. If This is possible then maybe i can find a Way To automatically comment on youtube
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't be done. Not sure why you would even want to.

Comment: "I am looking for..." is not a real question, is it? Please read the [tour] and learn [ask] here!

Comment: Automatic commenting is synonymous with *spam*, yes?  No one here wants to help you spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do with batch files, but look into VBScript, it has a "SendKeys" function which is like a typer and you can click in sertain positions.
Which means you could create a program that clicks in the comment box and types, then presses "Post".

Comment: Never mind python is much better for this

Comment: This might help you:
https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter18/

Comment: I mean really, depending on how they're planning on using it, Javascript may be best for this.

Comment: holy christ, this was a long time ago. thanks though!